Leave PopoverPanel after Link Clicked
In my Vue Project ive a Navbar Component with a Dashboard (Popover), how can i fadeout the PopoverPanel when i click a link inside of it:
ive tried using bool and v-if but its confusing and im seaarching for a more simpler answer.
        <Popover class="relative">
          <PopoverButton class="flex items-center gap-x-1 text-sm/6 font-semibold text-[#E0D8DE] hover:text-[#949D6A]"
          >
            Dashboard
            <ChevronDownIcon class="size-5 flex-none text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" />
          </PopoverButton>

          <transition
            @after-leave="isOpen = false"
            enter-active-class="transition ease-out duration-200" 
            enter-from-class="opacity-0 translate-y-1" 
            enter-to-class="opacity-100 translate-y-0" 
            leave-active-class="transition ease-in duration-150" 
            leave-from-class="opacity-100 translate-y-0" 
            leave-to-class="opacity-0 translate-y-1"
            >
          <PopoverPanel class="absolute -left-8 top-full z-10 mt-3 w-screen max-w-md overflow-hidden rounded-3xl bg-[#1a1a1a] shadow-lg ring-1 ring-gray-900/5">
            <div class="p-4">
              <div v-for="item in products" :key="item.name" class="group relative flex items-center gap-x-6 rounded-lg p-4 text-sm/6 hover:bg-[#423E37]">
                <div class="flex size-11 flex-none items-center justify-center rounded-lg bg-gray-50 group-hover:bg-white">
                  <component :is="item.icon" class="size-6 text-gray-600 group-hover:text-indigo-600" aria-hidden="true" />
                </div>
                <div class="flex-auto">
                  <router-link 
                    v-if="item.href" 
                    :to="item.href" 
                    class="block font-semibold text-[#949D6A]"               
                    >
                    {{ item.name }}
                  </router-link>
                  <p class="mt-1 text-[#E0D8DE]">{{ item.description }}</p>
                </div>
               </div>
              </div>
              <div class="grid grid-cols-2 divide-x divide-gray-900/5 bg-gray-50">
                <a v-for="item in callsToAction" :key="item.name" :href="item.href" class="flex items-center justify-center gap-x-2.5 p-3 text-sm/6 font-semibold text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-100">
                  <component :is="item.icon" class="size-5 flex-none text-gray-400" aria-hidden="true" />
                  {{ item.name }}
                </a>
              </div>
            </PopoverPanel>
          </transition>
        </Popover>
      </PopoverGroup>

